# What's the longest time between when a question was asked and when the first accepted answer was entered?

Tags: discussion, badges, accepted-answer, statistics

I've gotten a few Necromancer badges for answering questions that were months or even a couple of years old.  In some cases, the OP came back around to grant my answer as the accepted solution.

It got me wondering this:

What's the longest length in time from when an OP posted a question to when the *first accepted answer* was entered?

Don't count the time for when the OP came back to accept. Don't count answers to questions that already had an accepted answer.

Comment: This seems like a candidate for SEDE?

Comment: 42[.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416106/whats-the-longest-time-between-when-a-question-was-asked-and-when-the-first-acc)

Comment: We don't know yet, that answer hasn't been posted yet.

Comment: @EatenbyaGrue How do you write such short comments? I promise to be responsible :-).

Comment: @SylvesterKruin the period is a link to this question

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is [the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1560778)

```sql
select top 10 
       datediff(d, q.creationdate, a.creationdate) [days]
     , q.id [Post Link]
     , q.creationdate
     , q.score [q score]
     , a.creationdate [ Accepted Answer Created] 
     , a.score [a score]
     , v.creationdate [Accepted by OP on]
from posts q
inner join posts a on a.id = q.acceptedanswerid
inner join votes v on v.postid = a.id and votetypeid = 1
where q.posttypeid = 1 -- Question
order by datediff(d, q.creationdate, a.creationdate) desc
```

The answer is: 4685 days for this question [How to convert a week (200851) into a date (2008-12-27)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506827/how-to-convert-a-week-200851-into-a-date-2008-12-27)

Note that we don't have public info which answers have been accepted and unaccepted during the life-time of a Q/A. We only know the current state.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the fine [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the admirable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: Wow, I was under the impression that the votes table included that info. TIL.

Comment: @Braiam yeah, it is something you would expect but the logic for accept votes is that the previous vote is "undone", as if it never happened. Similar to unupvote and undownvote, those aren't found in the votes table either. It is a pitty.

Comment: 4685 days is ~12.83561644 years, in case anyone's wondering.

Comment: Up next: write a bot that automatically updates this answer every month or so, or every time the stats would change :-).

Comment: @SylvesterKruin up next: a bot that finds an unanswered question that has been unanswered slightly longer than the answer to this question, and answers it.

Comment: Now to figure out the query to find the oldest unanswered questions by users that have logged on within the last year

Comment: @abligh do know we have a fine site (which I might or might not be affiliated with) where you find info on how to create such a bot by leveraging the Stack API: https://stackapps.com/

Comment: "Note that we don't have public info which answers have been accepted and unaccepted during the life-time of a Q/A. " Then isn't your query showing the largest gap between asking date and the accepted answer date?  That's much different than what was asked .  Maybe there is then no solid answer possible due to lack of data..

Comment: Be right back, about to close a question about December 2008 as no longer applicable.